# SQL Feed Query results into Union All Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, union-all

I have a COTS application database that creates a new table every week that follows a specific naming convention and always contains the same columns.  I have written a query to select the tables within a certain time range:

```
DECLARE @today VARCHAR(8)
SET @today = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)

DECLARE @monthold VARCHAR(8)
SET @monthold = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),dateadd(day,-31,@today),112)

SELECT name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name <= 'Event_Audit'+ @today AND name >= 'Event_Audit'+ @monthold 
AND name like 'Event_Audit%'
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Now I am looking for a way to have a query call each of the tables that is selected to aggregate the data.  This will be used for SSRS reporting.

Something like this where table1, table2, etc. through all the included tables will get populated (whether it is 4, 5, or more):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table2
UNION ALL
...
ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC
```

I can't create views, new tables, or make any changes to existing tables.

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL, but what's the actual problem you have? Have you tried using sp_executesql?

Comment: I was trying to use T-SQL.  I will do some further reading on dynamic SQL and sp_executesql.

Comment: All the articles I have seen so far reference creating a new table or a temporary table which I can't do.  The accounts only have read access to the SQL DB for pulling report data.

Comment: Check user permission....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poor design will lead to hard work every time, this one is no exception. I'm guessing by now it's too late to give up the idea of creating the same table over and over again for each month.

You do not need to create a new or temporary table to execute sp_executeSql, you only need to generate the sql script:

```
DECLARE  @today char(8) = CONVERT(char(8),GETDATE(),112),
         @monthold char(8) = CONVERT(char(8),dateadd(day,-31,GETDATE()),112),
         @sql nvarchar(max) = ''



SELECT @Sql = @Sql + ' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM ' + name
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name <= 'Event_Audit'+ @today AND name >= 'Event_Audit'+ @monthold 
AND name like 'Event_Audit%'
ORDER BY name DESC

SET @SQL = STUFF(@SQL, 1, 11, '') + -- remove the first UNION ALL
    ' ORDER BY EVENT_DATE DESC' -- add the ORDER BY

PRINT @Sql
--EXEC sp_executeSql @Sql
```

Once you've printed the @Sql and checked it's ok, unremark the EXEC line and run your script.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  Unfortunately it is a COTS product so I have no control over their DB tables.